# (2002) Error:Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (46)

Tags: mysql

Please help..

I am using yahoo small business web hosting. I have uploaded the files to the server and database also. I had given the host name as 'mysql'. Still cant access the site.

Comment: What OS are you using for MySQL?

Comment: @MiyaG I am using windows 7

Comment: MySQL is also installed on win 7 right?

Comment: @MiyaG I am not sure whether it is installed in windows 7. I am using yahoo web hosting service.

Comment: Okay, on Linux sometime this type errors accours due to mysql.sock file stored in mysql directory like `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`. To solve this issue when have to move `mysql.sock` to `mysql.sock.old` and restart MySQL server. But here you are not sure about OS. so please ask to your service provider to solve the issue.

Comment: @MiyaG thank you for your reply. Let me check it with the service provider.

Comment: @Anu this is not happening on Windows for sure as /tmp/mysql.sock is a Unix Domain Socket path ...

Answer (score 2):

With YaHoo Webservices mysql seems to run on a different machine than your code, so you need to connect to host `mysql` instead of `localhost`:

See YaHoo Help "[Why can't I access my database?](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/yahoo-web-hosting/SLN20633.html)"

Comment: I had already given the host as mysql. But it is not working.

Comment: First I had given the host as localhost. At that time the error wad different. Later I put the host name as mysql. This time i am getting the socket error((2002) Error:Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (46))

Comment: I tried again with host as mysql. Now getting the error (1045) Error:Access denied for user 'alintishar_db'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: And this is the username/password combination you've given when creating the database (as described in https://help.yahoo.com/kb/yahoo-web-hosting/set-mysql-database-account-sln20602.html )?

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the **my.cnf** on program files
2. Change the default socket location to **'/tmp/mysq.sock'**
3. Restart `Mysql`

Comment: You missed the "YaHoo Web Hosting" part of the story. User doesn't have control over the mysql server, and it is not running on the same host as the code anyway so Unix Domain Socket communication can't even be used here, no matter what socket file name ...

Comment: @anu ,check your user privileges and password too